# How to add multiple images to a qweb report in odoo?

Tags: xml, image, report, odoo, qweb

I want to provide an option to attach multiple images while creating a quotation and then when that is printed, it has to be displayed in the PDF report also.

I was successful in handling the above scenario with single image by this:

In py -

```
name = fields.Binary(string="Upload", required=False)
```

In XML -

```
<img t-attf-src="data:image/*;base64,{{doc.image_field_name}}"/>
```

But when it comes to multiple images, I am guessing its a little complex. Can someone guide me how to achieve this? I even tried the many2many field, but didn't work.

Comment: Depends a bit on the field you will define in python. But QWeb (xml) can use loops, so there is no problem looping through a many2many or one2many field in QWeb.

Comment: @CZoellner the problem in my case is, I tried using many2many binary widget, but it is throwing error - "can't access property "addclass", widget.$el is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could log a note or notes with the images attached to it and then use the field "message_ids" and get the related attachments with "message_ids.attachment_ids", then you could foreach the images logged:

```
<t t-foreach="doc.message_ids.attachment_ids" t-as="attachment">
    <img t-att-src="attachment.image_src"/>
</t>
```